# Why do I receive the "duplicate sources" error message during an Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD session?

Tags: software-sources, live-environment

When I boot the Ubuntu 12.04 desktop Live CD and run the command `sudo apt-get update`, the final messages are the warning messages below.

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20120425)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20120425)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

However, there do **not** appear to be any duplicate sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list

deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

I also ran the command `gksudo software-properties-gtk` and noticed that there are two entries under the **Other Software** tab for `Cdrom with Ubuntu 12.04 'Precise Pangolin'`

[image]

Removing these two entries in **Other Software** also eliminates the `Duplicate sources.list entry` warning messages from `apt-get update` (as well as other `apt-get` functions).

I do not understand why those two entries for `Cdrom with Ubuntu` are present in the **Other Software** tab. The CD is also already selected as a possible install source under the **Ubuntu Software** tab. That should be enough, shouldn't it?

[image]

Is there an error in the Ubuntu 12.04 Live environment's default configuration of Software Sounces? Or am I doing something (else) wrong?

Is it OK to remove the `Cdrom` entries under **Other Software** to eliminate the `W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom:` message?

---

**Update:**

I forgot to look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` after removing the entries from the **Other Software** tab. After doing that its contents becomes:

```
# /etc/apt/sources.list

deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

I'm still confused as to what is going on here. Is
`dists/precise/main/binary-i386/` and
`dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/` the same thing as
`precise main restricted`??

I didn't think so when I first looked at it, but then again removing those entries eliminates the `Duplicate sources.list` warning messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that the Precise AMD64 internet repositories also include the **i386** repositories *by default*. I assume the reason is so that you can seamlessly install and run i386 programs after simply installing `ia32-libs`.

It looks like this is also true for the CDROM repos -- that's all there is to it.

Here's what an extremely simple one-line `sources.list` does on an AMD64 Precise system:

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted`

- `sudo apt-get update` output (note `Get:5` and `Get:6`):

  ```
  Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
  Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]
  Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]
  Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages [1,273 kB]
  Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages [8,452 B]                 
  Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main ***i386*** Packages [1,274 kB]                       
  Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted ***i386*** Packages [8,431 B]                  
  Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex [3,706 B]                     
  Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex [2,596 B]               
  Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en [726 kB]                        
  Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en [2,395 B]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You see this, because it's a bug =)
You shouldn't see it.
Filed as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1015495
after discussing with cjwatson.